# Comparing two lists lexically

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

I have two lists of integers `a` and `b` of equal length, and I would like to define `a>b` as follows: let `i` be the smallest index such that `a[[i]]>b[[i]]` (if there is one), and `j` the smallest integer such that `a[[j]]<b[[j]]`. Then `a>b` if `i>j`. In other words, marching left to right across both lists, the first is greater than the second if the first position you encounter where the two lists are unequal has a greater value in `a` than in `b`.

So for example `{1,2,1} > {1,1,4}` since the lists first differ in position 2, and there the first is greater than the second.

I know how to do this using a loop, but that seems remarkably inappropriate.

Another method is by comparing `Position[Map[# > 0 &, a-b], True, 1]` and `Position[Map[# < 0 &, a-b], True, 1]`, or `Position[Thread[Greater[a,b]],True,1]` and `Position[Thread[Less[a,b]],True,1]`. But both of these fail without additional code in the case where one or the other returns an empty list. Is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple of possibilities.

```
inOrder1[a_List, a_] := 0
inOrder1[a_List, b_List] /; MatrixQ[{a, b}, IntegerQ] := 
 Sign[First[a - b /. 0 -> Sequence[]]]

In[8]:= inOrder1[{1, 2, 1}, {1, 4, 0}]

(* Out[8]= -1 *)

inOrder2[a_List, b_List] /; MatrixQ[{a, b}, IntegerQ] := Catch[
  Module[{sg}, 
   Scan[If[(sg = Sign[#[[1]] - #[[2]]]) != 0, Throw[sg]] &, 
    Transpose[{a, b}]]; 0]]

In[11]:= inOrder2[{1, 6, 1}, {1, 4, 0}]

(* Out[11]= 1 *)
```

These can be translated to `True/False` results if one wants to put them into `Sort` as an ordering predicate optional argument.

Another possibility is to just use `Sort` and hope it does what you want. (It might but then again even if it does, the internals could change in future.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is clearer, but as `Sort` using "lexical" ordering on same-length `List` comparison, I would transfer the original `List`s into same length ones, then invoke `Sort` on them:

```
Clear[lexicallySort]
lexicallySort[lst : {{_?NumericQ ..} ..}] := lst //
           Sort@PadRight[#,{Length@#,Max[Length/@#]},Min[#]-1]/.Evaluate[Min[#]-1]:>Sequence[] &

lexicallySort[{
               {1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3},
               {1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4},
               {1, 2, 1, 3},
               {1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1}, 
               {1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 4}, 
               {1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3}, 
               {1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3}, 
               {1, 2}, 
               {1, 3}
              }] // Grid
```

> ```
> 1 2           
> 1 2 1 3       
> 1 2 1 3 1 1   
> 1 2 1 3 1 1 1 3
> 1 2 1 3 1 1 1 4
> 1 2 1 3 1 3   
> 1 2 1 3 1 3 1 3
> 1 2 1 3 1 3 1 4
> 1 3
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I see the answer. I didn't realize that `Sort` on lists uses exactly [the inverse of] the sorting I want. So `!OrderedQ[a,b]`returns True exactly when `a>b`.